# htaccess without redirect HTTP & HTTPS non-www to HTTPS www

Tags: .htaccess, seo

i have SEO problem for http to https and non-www to https://www
Please help me how to solve this problem?

this is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} somefolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/somefolder/$1 [R,L]
# Ensure we are using HTTPS version of the site.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the latter rule, use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So now it redirects from all non-www. hosts to https://www, because the destination URL is changed.

Comment: its not working